# Search for string containing wild cards in python

Tags: python, string

I would like to search for wildcards in a string.

Here is the code I'm working with.

```
with open('file0001.mbx', 'r') as infile,open("ESAL_V.txt",'a') as ESAL_V, open("ESAL.txt", 'a') as ESAL:
        for line in infile: 
            if (str('ESAL15973P'))in line:
            ESAL_V.write(line)
            elif line.startswith("ESAL"):
                ESAL.write(line)
```

I would like to replace a few characters in the string search with wild cards. This is what I'd like to search for

```
if (str('ESAL*****P'))in line:
```

But this doesn't work. How do include these wild cards in the middle of my string search?

Comment: Of course it doesn't work; that is searching for literal asterisks, Python strings don't include the concept of wild cards. You will need to switch to [regular expressions](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/regex.html).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps you could use regex to mimic wildcard searching:

```
import re

if re.search(r'ESAL.{5}P', line):
     ESAL_V.write(line)
```

This checks `line` for the string 'ESAL' followed by any five characters followed by 'P'. If such a string is found, the `if` clause is `True`, else it's `False`.

If you want your wildcard matches to match only digits rather than *any* character (which includes spaces, punctuation, etc.), use `[0-9]{5}` instead of `.{5}`.

Answer (score 2):

If you're not familiar with regular expressions, you can use the module fnmatch, it works like wildcards, but you cannot specify the number of characters a star '*' would match.

```
import fnmatch
if fnmatch.fnmatch("*ESAL*P*",line):
```